# "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop, Version=7.1.40304.0' is not registered for COM Interop. Please register it with regasm.exe /tlb

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i have installed vs 2013, and i am trying to create my Custom VisualStudio tool, but when build my project i accrued this error:

```
The assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop, Version=7.1.40304.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not registered for COM Interop. Please register it with regasm.exe /tlb
```

i tried to register it with regasm but this not fixed my problem, my code looks like:

```
[Guid("6ECD98B5-C7E5-462E-8922-24890A8F3FE1")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class GPFDicKeyToEnumGenerator : BaseCodeGeneratorWithSite
    {
        protected override byte[] GenerateCode(string inputFileName, string inputFileContent)
        {
            return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
@"
using System;

namespace My.Name.Space
{
    public class foo
    {
    }
}
");
        }

        public override string GetDefaultExtension()
        {
            return ".cs";
        }

        #region Registration
        private static Guid CustomToolGuid =
            new Guid("{6ECD98B5-C7E5-462E-8922-24890A8F3FE1}");

        private static Guid CSharpCategory =
            new Guid("{FAE04EC1-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}");

        private const string CustomToolName = "GAMA.gpf.SDK.Tools";

        private const string CustomToolDescription = "Generate Enum of Keys for GPFDictionary";

        private const string KeyFormat
            = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{0}\Generators\{1}\{2}";

        protected static void Register(Version vsVersion, Guid categoryGuid)
        {
            string subKey = String.Format(KeyFormat,
                vsVersion, categoryGuid.ToString("B"), CustomToolName);

            using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(subKey))
            {
                key.SetValue("", CustomToolDescription);
                key.SetValue("CLSID", CustomToolGuid.ToString("B"));
                key.SetValue("GeneratesDesignTimeSource", 1);
            }
        }

        protected static void Unregister(Version vsVersion, Guid categoryGuid)
        {
            string subKey = String.Format(KeyFormat,
                vsVersion, categoryGuid.ToString("B"), CustomToolName);

            Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKey(subKey, false);
        }

        [ComRegisterFunction]
        public static void RegisterClass(Type t)
        {
            // Register for both VS.NET 2012, 2013 (C#)
            Register(new Version(11, 0), CSharpCategory);
            Register(new Version(12, 0), CSharpCategory);
        }

        [ComUnregisterFunction]
        public static void UnregisterClass(Type t)
        {
            // UnRegister for both VS.NET 2012, 2013 (C#)
            Register(new Version(11, 0), CSharpCategory);
            Register(new Version(12, 0), CSharpCategory);
        }

        #endregion Registration
    }
```

please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I changed the way that i used to register my tool, i used Attributes

Comment: @PeterFromCologne i posts the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the way that i used to register my tool:

i used the Attributes class looks like:

```
public class GPFToolAttribute : Attribute
{
        /// <summary></summary>
protected string _description;

/// <summary></summary>
protected string _name;

    // Constructors
    public GPFToolAttribute(){

    }

public string Description
{
  get { return _description; }
}

        /// <summary>
///
/// </summary>
public string Name
{
  get { return _name; }
}

        /// <summary>
///
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name"></param>
public GPFToolAttribute(string name) :

  this(name, "")
{

}

        /// <summary>
///
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name"></param>
/// <param name="description"></param>
public GPFToolAttribute(string name, string description)
{
  _name = name;
  _description = description;
}
}
```

and the CodeGenerator class looks like:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
// TODO: Replace with your GUID
[Guid("24BCC6BC-D53F-497B-8455-0BE15568E6B3")]
[GPFToolAttribute("GPFEnumGenerator", "Generate an Enum conatins all the keys of a GPF Dictionary.")]
public class GPFEnumGenerator : BaseCodeGeneratorWithSite
{

    #region BaseCode generator methods
    public override string GetDefaultExtension()
    {
        // TODO: Replace with your implementation
        return ".cs";
    }

    protected override byte[] GenerateCode(string inputFileName, string inputFileContent)
    {

             string generatedCode = "Your code here";
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(generatedCode);
        }
    }
    #endregion 


    #region Registration

    [ComRegisterFunction]
    public static void RegisterClass(Type t)
    {
        GuidAttribute guidAttribute = getGuidAttribute(t);
        GPFToolAttribute customToolAttribute = getCustomToolAttribute(t);
        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(
          GetKeyName(CSharpCategoryGuid, customToolAttribute.Name)))
        {
            key.SetValue("", customToolAttribute.Description);
            key.SetValue("CLSID", "{" + guidAttribute.Value + "}");
            key.SetValue("GeneratesDesignTimeSource", 1);
        }
    }

    [ComUnregisterFunction]
    public static void UnregisterClass(Type t)
    {
        GPFToolAttribute customToolAttribute = getCustomToolAttribute(t);
        Registry.LocalMachine.DeleteSubKey(GetKeyName(
          CSharpCategoryGuid, customToolAttribute.Name), false);
    }



    internal static GuidAttribute getGuidAttribute(Type t)
    {
        return (GuidAttribute)getAttribute(t, typeof(GuidAttribute));
    }

    internal static GPFToolAttribute getCustomToolAttribute(Type t)
    {
        return (GPFToolAttribute)getAttribute(t, typeof(GPFToolAttribute));
    }

    internal static Attribute getAttribute(Type t, Type attributeType)
    {
        object[] attributes = t.GetCustomAttributes(attributeType, /* inherit */ true);
        if (attributes.Length == 0)
            throw new Exception(
              String.Format("Class '{0}' does not provide a '{1}' attribute.",
              t.FullName, attributeType.FullName));
        return (Attribute)attributes[0];
    }

    internal static string GetKeyName(Guid categoryGuid, string toolName)
    {
        return
          String.Format("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\" + VisualStudioVersion +
            "\\Generators\\{{{0}}}\\{1}\\", categoryGuid, toolName);
    }


    #region Properties

    internal static Guid CSharpCategoryGuid = new Guid("FAE04EC1-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC");
    private const string VisualStudioVersion = "12.0";

    #endregion // Properties

    #endregion Registration
}
```